# Unable to execute 'DocumentBuilderFactory' in matlab

Tags: java, xml, matlab, viper

Whenever I am running the following command I getting an error given below. Please tell which jar file I need to add to run the command in Matlab.

Command: `docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();`

Error:

> Undefined variable "DocumentBuilderFactory" or class "DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance".

Comment: Have you tried `docBuilder = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();` instead?

Comment: Yes, its working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, the solution is to use the following line instead:

```
docBuilder = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
```